# Can i add more data to the fillable array in a laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

This is the default User model in laravel, can i add to the `fillable array`.
I want to create a login and register page
Whenever i add to the `fillable array`
My code doesn't seem to work could this be the problem

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

I want it to look like this
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'department', 'phone', 'status', 'username';
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I've removed the trailing semi-colon, Is that the only error on the page?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong syntax. Remove `;` from the end to make it work:

```
'username';
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'department', 'phone', 'status', 'username';
];
```

To

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'department', 'phone', 'status', 'username'
];
```

You have added a semicolon `;` after `username`, which is giving you an error

Comment: Thanks, I've done that; is that the only error on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use much element in to your fillable as well guarded property of the model as you want just remove ;(semicolon) from the code and write like

```
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'department', 'phone', 'status', 'username'
];
```